# Windows phone 8.1 application failed in release when I use background tasks

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, background-task

I added a background task to my Windows Phone 8.1 app. And it works as expected, but only in `Debug` mode. I always get the `RootFrame_NavigationFailed` exception when I run my application in `Release` mode.

How can I debug it in `Release` to know the reason of the `RootFrame_NavigationFailed`?

The app doesn't have any information in exception in `Release` mode.

Comment: What kind of background tasks are you using? Where/when exactly do you get the error?

Comment: Windows Runtime Component (.winmd). When I run my app.

Comment: How your BTask is triggered (TimeTrigger, Maintance)? Or it's BackgroundAudio task? How it's connected with your App? Have you tried to debug Suspending event?

Comment: It's the timer background task which I referenced to my app. I can't use debug events, because I've got exception instantly after my app run.

Comment: But you have said that it works in Debug mode. If you remove BTask from the code - does the app work fine? Are you able to say what lines cause the problem? Or maybe you are able to share a project with the problem?

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly work in DEBUG mode. I can't say what lines cause the problem, because if I can I'll know what to fix or avoid :) I started to remove code line by line and figure out that the problem is in my library. I'll try to remove it's initialization from private variable to property or constructor and see what will happen. These are reasons why I can't write anything about the error: http://i.imgur.com/kP71PPC.png and http://i.imgur.com/8wAquYh.png

Comment: Removing some portions of code can help you to find the source of the problem. You may also try to save some things (exceptions's message) to a file, even in release mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after 2 weeks of trying to resolve this issue I moved my application to Windows Phone 8.1 runtime from Silverlight.

It costs me 3 evenings and my problem was disappeared. I'm very unhappy that this is the solution, but I can't figure out, what is really wrong. Because my library works great with background tasks in Windows Phone 8.1 runtime.